# Permutations and Combinations - Lists

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, permutations, combinations

Just want to verify my answers. This problem concerns lists made from the symbols A,B,C,D,E.
(a) How many such length-5 lists have at least one letter repeated?
(b) How many such length-6 lists have at least one letter repeated

(a)Possible length-5 lists = 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 = 3125.
Lists with no letters repeated = 5! = 120. 3125 - 120 = 3005.

(b)Possible length-6 lists = 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 = 15625
Lists with no letters repeated = 6! = 720. 15625 - 720 = 14905.

Comment: By the Pigeonhole principle, at least two places on the 6-letter strings must have identical letters. So all of them $5^6$ strings have at last 1 letter repeated. By the way how did you get $6!$?

Comment: So is my (a) correct?

Comment: Yes. (A) is correct.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what I did wrong. I'll have a look and let you know my new solution

Comment: (b) must be all of them, so 15625. Should have read the question :/